# checked list box Data Source Does

Tags: c#, .net, sqldatasource, checkedlistbox

I have bounded a `CheckedListBox` To a `DataSource` Which has been declared in class scope , but when I update `DataSource` in some method , `CheckedListBox` does not change , but when i recall following codes again it changes:

```
private void UpdateDataSource(string textToSearch )
{

    dsContacts = dbSms.fillDataSet("Select * From Contacts Where ContactName Like'%" + textToSearch + "%'", "Contacts");

    chListBox.DataSource = dsContacts.Tables["Contacts"];
    chListBox.DisplayMember = "ContactName";
    chListBox.ValueMember = "ContactNumber";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx) setter that's triggering the update. When you set it to a new value it will refresh the check list box.

Comment: how to be aware of updating ? i have declared DataSource in class scope

Comment: Yes but until you call the DataSource `setter` your control will not update. It keeps a copy of the original data source.

Comment: Every time you need to refresh the check box list control you need to call your `UpdateDataSource` method.

Answer (score 0):

> use refresh method.

```
private void UpdateDataSource(string textToSearch )
{

    dsContacts = dbSms.fillDataSet("Select * From Contacts Where ContactName Like'%" + textToSearch + "%'", "Contacts");

    chListBox.DataSource = dsContacts.Tables["Contacts"];
    chListBox.DisplayMember = "ContactName";
    chListBox.ValueMember = "ContactNumber";
    chListBox.Refresh();

}
```